# validation errors not showing individually in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magneto and i got shucked on the create account page my validation suddenly changed in to the image below

it was earlier it was good
[image: before]
but now it look like
[image: after]

how can i get back to previous style.

Comment: i resolved it .It was due to jquery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace you file with default file.. i think you have removed varient form validation script from page